# lenovo ideapad 320 suddenly stopped working in ubuntu 18.04

Tags: touchpad, lenovo

Touchpad in my lenovo ideapad was working fine but one day suddenly it stopped working.touchpad driver is detected in my system having ubuntu 18.04lts installed in it.I have newest version of touchpad driver in my system,i am not able to find why touchpad is not working..please help me out.[here is the list of input devices of my system](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pOqW9.png)
.[here is the version of driver installed](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FnT3T.png)

Comment: Welcome to askUbuntu!  While posting the output from the `terminal`, it is prefered to paste the text rather than putting screenshots.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe it is not a bug, maybe it is a feature... ;^)
Check the documentation from supplier for possible hot key or otherwise disabling of the touchpad. In that other OS this is common to have the touchpad disabled for when typing. Maybe you now have that feature enabled by accident. Just my 2c worth. Check your BIOS settings as well for such.